# excel formula depending on dynamic values in different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am trying to create an excel formula using SUM and SUMIF but cannot find how to.

I have a first column(A) which is the total time of a piece of work and then for each row the time spent in that task during each day(columns B, C, ...).

For each day(columns B, C, ...), the formula would return the sum of only those values in column A that(for that specific column), relate to task that have been completed that day: the sum of all cells within a row is equals or more than the time the task was allocated.

- Example for one 12-hours task:

```
    A   B  C  D  E    
    12  4  6  2  0
```

Using the formula:

```
    A   B  C  D  E
    12  4  6  2  0    
    0   0  0  12 0
```

where 12 is displayed in column D because  4 + 6 + 2 = 12(Column A)

---

- Second example(3 tasks):

```
    A   B  C  D  E    
    10  9  0  1  0    
    21  8  8  5  0    
    5   0  0  3  2
```

Using the formula:

```
    A   B  C  D  E    
    10  9  0  1  0    
    21  8  8  5  0
    5   0  0  3  2
    0   0  0  31 5
```

Where:

31(Day D) = 10(Task 1 is finished that day) + 21(Task 2 is finished that day too)

5(Day E) = Task 3 is finished that day

---

Tried this formula (for Day B):

```
 SUMIF(B1:B3,">=A1:A3",A1:A3)
```

(Sum those values in column A if the cells in that row p to column B(in this case just B) are >= than those iterated).

Then for column C, it would be,

```
SUMIF(C1:C3 + B1:B3,">=A1:A3",A1:A3)
```

The above examples did not work(first returns zero, second is an invalid formula), 
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What would the formula be for column D?  Also, what results are you getting with those formulas?

Comment: Thanks. In the last example, result is zero(=SUMIF(B1:B3,">A1:A3",A1:A3)) for first formula and alert with syntax error for the second. I guess for column D would be SUMIF(D1:D3 + C1:C3 + B1:B3,">A1:A3",A1:A3), basically if all cells in a row are more in value than the first cell of that row add the value of that first cell to the result that is returned by the formula.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to do with the + symbols?

Comment: replacing in the formulas "," to ";"

Comment: No, row. so if a row is "13 7 4 2 0" it means is a 13-hour task and the formula will add 13 in the last row in the column where all cells are 13. So, column 4 has accumulated value of 13: 7 + 4 + 2 therefore add 13 to the sum that does this for every task/row. The idea is if in day C three tasks have been finished then you add the total time each of the three had.

Comment: So does this formula go below the rows or to their side?

Comment: + is to add the values of two cells, so sum A1 only if B1+C2>=A1

Comment: below is basically adding all task durations that have been completed that day.

Comment: So, just to be clear, for Day B (your first formula), the answer should be 0?

Comment: yes. In the second example there are three rows and the fouth is created by the formula. In that fourth row, there are values 31(because a 10 and a 11 task were completed) and 5 because a 5-hour task was finished(for that task, 3 hours in day D, 2 in day E).

Comment: Does this have a max number of projects or does it need to be expandable?

Comment: I can't figure it out.  The closest I've come is this, and it doesn't do what you want, but it might get you on the right path:
(Used in column D): IF(SUM(B1:D1)>=SUM(A1),SUM(A1),0)+IF(SUM(B2:D2)>=SUM(A2),SUM(A2),0)+IF(SUM(B3:D3)>=SUM(A3),SUM(A3),0).

Comment: Is just one sheet with many rows/tasks and the formula is required to add up acumulated hours in a task if the task is finished in that column.

Comment: it did, thanks! a bit modified: =IF(SUM(B1:D1)=A1,A1,0)+IF(SUM(B2:D2)=A2,A2,0)+IF(SUM(B3:D3)=A3,A3,0)+IF(SUM(B4:D4)=A4,A4,0)  The only problem is that it should not be if + if + if but sum (all ifs) to make it generic and easy to add new rows, but the idea is good. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered VBA for this? I avoid complex formula unless what I'm doing has to be super efficient then I'll create a complex formula. Otherwise, it's VBA all the way. The good thing about custom VBA functions is that you name the parameters which make it super easy for users to consume.

Comment: Also check out ExcelDNA to make custom Excel functions using .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Formula below given by user ServerS works fine:

Col B:

```
=IF(SUM(B2)=A2,A2,0)+IF(SUM(B3)=A3,A3,0)+IF(SUM(B4)=A4,A4,0)+IF(SUM(B5)=A5,A5,0)
```

Col C:

```
=IF(SUM(B2:C2)=A2,A2,0)+IF(SUM(B3:C3)=A3,A3,0)+IF(SUM(B4:C4)=A4,A4,0)+IF(SUM(B5:C5)=A5,A5,0)
```

Col D

```
=IF(SUM(B2:D2)=A2,A2,0)+IF(SUM(B3:D3)=A3,A3,0)+IF(SUM(B4:D4)=A4,A4,0)+IF(SUM(B5:D5)=A5,A5,0)
```

However there are two inconvenients:
if new rows are added it needs to be adapted and include another IF(). Would be better to have a generic SUM if IF's
Trying to propagate the formula to adjacent cells is not possible as it would change part of the formula like "=A2,A2,0" to "=A3,A3,0" which needs to keep the same.

Any other ideas that improve this, if possible, are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using IF with a sumproduct. This method allows use to insert any row you want. Make sure range are correct (eg A2:A5 with 5 the last row used). I would go for this :

in column B :

```
=SOMMEPROD(($A$2:$A$5)*($A$2:$A$5=(B2:B5)))
```

in column C :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5)*($A$2:$A$5=(B2:B5+C2:C5)))-B6
```

in column D

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5)*($A$2:$A$5=(B2:B5+C2:C5+D2:D5)))-C6-B6
```

in column E

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5)*($A$2:$A$5=(B2:B5+C2:C5+D2:D5+E2:E5)))-D6-C6-B6
```

[image: SUMPRODUCT]